# Tabularray: tblr inside table environment affects pagebreak longtblr and mixes the two tables

Tags: tables, floats, page-breaking, tabularray

I try to place a `talltblr` environment from `Tabularray` inside a `table` environment. However, this is messing up the pagebreak from the `longtblr` table above it. It somehow ends up inside the `longtblr`. The same thing happens when I change `talltblr` to `tblr`. I assumed the `table` environment would give me a better page layout (verticle space, placement etc). Is it not recommended to place a `tblr` inside a `table` environment?

See the MWE below and a picture of the outcome with and without the `table` environment wrapped around `(tall)tblr`. Blue header of `longtblr`, red header of `talltblr`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}% Colors
\usepackage{tabularray}%
    \UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}%

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\section{Long table error}

Text needed 1?

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long tblr caption},% Caption
]{
    colspec = {lX},
    rowhead = 1,%               # rows footer, header
        hline{1,Z}  = {1pt},%   top & bottomrule
        hline{2}    = {0.3pt},% midrule
        row{1}      = {cyan},
}
% Header
    Head 1      & Head 2 \\
% Table
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
\end{longtblr}

Text needed 2?

\begin{table}
  \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {Tall tblr caption},% Caption
]{
    colspec     = {ll},
        hline{1,Z}  = {1pt},%   top & bottomrule
        hline{2}    = {0.3pt},% midrule
        row{1}      = {purple},
}
% Header
    Head 1      & Head 2 \\
% Table
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
  \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

Text needed 3?

\end{document}
```

With `table` environment:
Blue header of `longtblr`, red header of `talltblr`.
[image: With table 1][image: With table 2]

Without `table` environment:
Blue header of `longtblr`, red header of `talltblr`.
[image: Without table 1][image: Without table 2]

Comment: table is a float, and so it can float to the top of the page. When you mix floating and non floating tables then it can happen that you have to correct the placement to get the numbering and order right.

Answer (score 2):

Many users would think it is a trap when they discover some day that the default option of a `table` environment is `tbp` without `h` in it, which tell LaTeX not to try to put the table "here" (current position).

In most of the time it is a good idea to set the placement option of a `table` environment to `!htbp`. In this example, `!hbp` is a better choice, since it is after a long table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}% Colors
\usepackage{tabularray}%
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath,booktabs}%

%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
%--------------------------------------------------------------%
\section{Long table error}

Text needed 1?

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Long tblr caption},% Caption
]{
    colspec = {lX},
    rowhead = 1,%               # rows footer, header
        hline{1,Z}  = {1pt},%   top & bottomrule
        hline{2}    = {0.3pt},% midrule
        row{1}      = {cyan},
}
% Header
    Head 1      & Head 2 \\
% Table
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
\end{longtblr}

Text needed 2?

\begin{table}[!hbp]
  \begin{talltblr}[
    caption = {Tall tblr caption},% Caption
]{
    colspec     = {ll},
        hline{1,Z}  = {1pt},%   top & bottomrule
        hline{2}    = {0.3pt},% midrule
        row{1}      = {purple},
}
% Header
    Head 1      & Head 2 \\
% Table
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
            \hline
    AA          & 1 \\
    BB          & 2 \\
    CC          & 3 \\
    DD          & 4 \\
  \end{talltblr}
\end{table}

Text needed 3?

\end{document}
```

[image]

For better control of the position of a `table` environment, you may see answers to these questions:

[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

[Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

There is also an issue about clearing floats before a `longtblr` environment:

https://github.com/lvjr/tabularray/issues/60

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution to my problem! Would you advice to place a float block for all the longtblrs instead of controlling the position of the tables? For example like this: \AddToHook{env/longtblr/begin}{\FloatBlock}

Comment: @Elise I can not answer this because I haven’t done any test in long documents.

Comment: That is not a problem. Thank you very much for your solution!